# Referencing not working for multiple pictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing

I want to reference 2 pictures, but one is always shown as ?? in the pdf. I do not know what I am doin wrong. Below you find an example that reproduces this problem. Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

```
    
    
    \makeatletter
    \makeatother
    \usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
    

    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{caption}


    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{latexsym}
    \usepackage{lmodern}    % The Font Type
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{xspace}

    
    
    \makeatletter
    \makeatother
    \usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
    

    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{caption}


    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{latexsym}
    \usepackage{lmodern}    % The Font Type
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{xspace} 
    
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks,
        citecolor=black,
        filecolor=black,
        linkcolor=black,
        urlcolor=black
    }


    
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[h] 
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
                \centering
                
                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                    \draw (0,0)--(11,0)--(11,7)--(0,7)--cycle;

                    \end{tikzpicture}

                \label{fig:A}
                \caption{Some text.}
            \end{minipage}
            \hskip60pt
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
                \centering

                    \begin{tikzpicture} %, fill=ashgrey!25
                    \path[draw, line width=0.5mm] (0,0) -- (13,0) -- (13,11) -- (0,11) -- (0,0)--cycle;
                    \end{tikzpicture}

                \caption{Some text.}
                \label{fig:B}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}


     Some text \ref{fig:A} \ref{fig:B}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: `\label{fig:A}                \caption{Some text.}` label has to be in or after caption, not before.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed it.